# App was created for an older version of Android and may not work properly

Tags: php, android, zxing

To the team.

Until 2 weeks ago I used a PHP app that worked perfectly on my mobile. He reads the barcode and finds the product.
However, last week, I tried to read a regular barcode EAN13 and I get the following message from the zxing website:

*barcode scanner
This app was created for an older version of Android and may not work properly. Try to check for updates or contact the develope*r

Version off may Andoid: N970FXXU8HIVJ6 from October 1, 2022

I updated the app and it didn't work.
Does anyone have news or could guide me on how to proceed?

My best regards.

Get guidance to solve the problem, with someone who has been through the same situation.

Comment: Give a link or something to the app you're talking about

Comment: This message appears to apps with outdated ```targetSdkVersion``` , it doesn't affect the app in any way and can still be used

Comment: I'm also facing the same behavior here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016486/play-store-fails-to-detect-device-compatibility Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?